# How to make this to a proper DateTime.TryParse()

Tags: c#

How would I make this into a try parse?

```
private static DateTime _endDate = DateTime.Parse(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EndDate"])
```

is it just

```
private static DateTime _endDate = DateTime.TryParse(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EndDate"], out Datetime _endDate)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would be:

```
private static DateTime _endDate;
if (!DateTime.TryParse(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EndDate"], out _endDate)) {
    // handle failure
}
```

Naturally the `if` part has to be in your constructor, it can't be loose in the class declaration.

Comment: lose the `DateTime` at the end ;-)

Comment: Thx @Daniel, fixed.  I originally cut+pasted the "wrong" code and repaired the most egregious error.

Comment: No problem, just wanted to make sure, your answer is correct, when it gets upvotes :-)

Comment: What's about Culture like en-US, es-ES, etc ?

Comment: @Kiquenet: That wouldn't meet the requirements stated in the question, specifically being equivalent to the `DateTime.Parse` version given, would it?

Answer (score 3):

No, because `TryParse` returns a `bool`.

You need to think about what you want to do if the parsing fails. For example, you might want a default - in which case you could write a method such as:

```
public static DateTime ParseWithDefault(string text, DateTime defaultValue)
{
    DateTime ret;
    if (!DateTime.TryParse(text, out ret))
    {
        ret = defaultValue;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

... and then call *that* from your initializer. If that isn't the behaviour you want, you need to work out what you *do* want... but the variable initializer has to be an expression of type `DateTime` (or implicitly convertible to it).

If you need more complex logic, you could potentially use a static constructor for it.

Comment: This would provide an enterprise solution that would scale easily assuming all dates were parsed through this device. I overloaded it to allow just the text and defaulted the default to allow a global default. +1

Answer (score 0):

```
var date = "01/01/2001";

DateTime result;

if (DateTime.TryParse(date, out result))
{
    // it worked
}
```

Give that a shot..

Answer (score 0):

DateTime.TryParse returns a boolean, so you cannot assign a DateTime to it. You should declare it first, and then assigni ts success to a boolean.

```
private static DateTime _endDate;
private bool success = _endDate.TryParse(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EndDate"], out _endDate);
```